# What is interpretation for bundleForClass returns nil and how that can be corrected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, tdd, nsbundle

I am preparing an XCTest and to perform the test I need to load a resource from test bundle. Therefore I use:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"item" ofType:@"plist"];
```

The problem is that `bundleForClass` returns `nil`. How can that be happening, as every class is tied to a bundle which was loaded from? Is there any setting to be corrected to make it working?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"item" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: [NSBundle allBundles] returns nil as well

Comment: so where is `item.plist` ?is it in project?

Comment: Its included via Xcode into UnitTest bundle. It is test data to perform a test on creating object from serialised data on disk, so it's not a part of original application.

Comment: The following line is not an issue, as when I get proper bundle it will find appropriate path